# Run time Error 5 but only for one item of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code which I am using to populate a pivot with data and create an email with a pdf attached.

```
i = 4 
Do While Sheets("Dunning").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "Grand Total" 
    Sheets("Overdue Notification Template").Select 
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Overdue Template").PivotFields("Policy Id").CurrentPage = Worksheets("Dunning").Cells(i, 1).Value
```

It's the last line which causes the problem - it runs for the first 8 data items and then gives a run time error 5.  If I add a `On error resume` line to the code it ignores this one data item and runs the rest completely fine.

I've tried changing the data items to see if I can spot an error in the data but there is nothing different form any of the other items in the list.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would happen?  I'm guessing it isn't the code because it runs fine for every other data item.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would probably help a little if we could at least see the line that causes the error, in the absence of any other information. ;)

Comment: i = 4
Do While Sheets("Dunning").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "Grand Total"
    Sheets("Overdue Notification Template").Select
                                                              
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Overdue Template").PivotFields("Policy Id").CurrentPage = Worksheets("Dunning").Cells(i, 1).Value                                              It's the last line which causes the problem. sorry, first time using this site :)

Comment: That just sounds like one of the values is wrong or perhaps of the wrong type, try using: `.CurrentPage = CStr(Worksheets("Dunning").Cells(i, 1).Value)`

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a try

Comment: same problem :( It's got to be something simple with the actual data but I can't see it.  Time to leave it and go back to it tomorrow I think

Comment: Then I'd guess that item doesn't exist. Hard to say when we can't see anything!

Comment: yes.  unfortunately can't share the data  but thanks for the comments

Comment: try debug.print Worksheets("Dunning").Cells(i, 1).Value before assigning it to check the values.